# Erro ao executar um código de "módulo"

Tags: python

Ao executar um exercício sobre módulo, acontece o seguinte "erro TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting,"  o que está acontecendo?

```
#coding: utf-8
num = input("Digite um número: ")
if(num % 2 ==0):
    print("o número é par")
else: 
    print("o número é impar")
```

Comment: "seguinte erro"? Não encontrei o erro na pergunta.

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O retorno do input  é  string. Para corrigir, você deve converter usando `int()`

Assim:

```py
num = int(input("Digite um número: "))
```

Comment: Compreendi!! Então o tutorial está errado?http://excript.com/python/modulo-da-divisao-python.html

Comment: Eu olhei agora e sim: o código está errado.

Comment: Se essa resposta te ajudou, marque-a como correta.

Comment: @RaulNascimento Inclusive nessa página tem um comentário de 2017 apontando o erro (e uma resposta do moderador do site reconhecendo que está errado), mas até hoje não corrigiram...